# How to select two random values from two strings if both the strings contains same values

Tags: jmeter, controller

two drop downs

1)Array _ depart city contains N cities
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,......nnn

2)Array _ arrival city contains N cities
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,......nnn

want to select two cities from two strings randomly but two cities should not match

Answer (score 1):

You can include following in a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

```
def cities =["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","test"]

//Remove a random city and assign to dep_city
cities.shuffle()
def dep_city = cities.pop()

//Remove a random city and assign to arrival_city
cities.shuffle()
def arrival_city= cities.pop()

//Setting the variables 
vars.put("dep_city", dep_city)
vars.put("arrival_city", arrival_city)

SampleResult.setIgnore() //Result is not generated
```

[Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html) is used for the scripting
[Shuffle](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#shuffle()) is used to randomly reorder the elements
[Pop](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#pop()) is used to remove the first element from the list

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't think your approach is correct, test needs to be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) and your "random" logic may lead to the situation when one test run reveals performance problem and the next one doesn't because the data is different.

So maybe it makes more sense to consider using [parameterization](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) instead, i.e. put all the cities to the CSV file and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read them.

---

If you **really** want your test to use random data and you have these "arrays" in form of string like in your question you can implement the randomization using any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the example code like:

```
def dep_array = 'aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff'
def arr_array = 'aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff'

def getRandomCity(String cities, Object prev) {
    def array = cities.split(',')
    def rv = array[org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, array.size())]
    if (prev != null) {
        if (rv == prev) {
            rv = getRandomCity(array.join(','), prev)
        }
    }
    return rv
}

def dep_city = getRandomCity(dep_array, null)

def arr_city = getRandomCity(arr_array, dep_city)

vars.put('dep_city', dep_city)
vars.put('arr_city', arr_city)
```

You will be able to access the values as `${dep_city}` and `${arr_city}` later on where required